# Website to Android

Tags: android, web, native

I want to build an Android app that represents my website and I need some guidance on how to approach this. My website is an ecommerce shop made by www.modified-shop.org and it has a complex mysql database structure. If I am to build a native app, would it be wise to create a simpler data model with only the info I need, then convert it to sqlite and make it part of the app's installation? If so, what should be the maximum size of this sqlite db?
Also, should I be handling the data update when the user starts the app through an android service?

Comment: This is not the site to promote your website

Comment: I don't think he has done that. He didn't even mention the url from his site.

Comment: I only mentioned the creator of my website, just to get a feel of what kind of site I am trying to convert to a native app...and initially I would only showcase my products.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own API to return only what you need and then in your app use this api to get and set your data into you Mysql DB on the server.

You can use sqllite to cache some results etc.

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you please help me understand what you suggest...you're saying to create a simpler db model on the server and have the app query this db when the user is using it? so I should not carry all the data in a sqlite db as part of the app's installation?

Comment: you can leave your mysqldb asis, but create API above it to return\change only neccessary objects - for example if you have an item with 20 fields you can create simple object in your app with 5 fields and create API method that parse this 5 fields from you mysql db and return them. After first start of the app you can download some important data and cache it. While using app user will download small pieces of information and maybe you can store it in your db. Check this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE